# Camera App Supported Orientation?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to do the same as Camera app: it looks like only Portrait mode is supported but when you rotate certain views get rotated while toolbar and some controls are in the same place.

I tried to disable all supported orientation in PLIST file but this calls no delegate method such as shouldRotate, or, obviously, willRotate to perform orientation change.

When supported orientation are in PLIST, iPhone rotates all views, even though I return NO for shouldRotate method.

How to solve such dilemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `info.plist`, set the only supported orientation to `Portrait`. Then, in you `viewDidLoad` method, add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

This will call the method:

```
- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)aNotification; {
  UIDeviceOrientation currentDeviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

  switch(currentDeviceOrientation){
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
      break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
      break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
      break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

From there, you can do whatever you want based on any option. Also, don't forget to add this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

To you dealloc method. Hope that Helps!